# Working with javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have a php script that successfully gets an array of data from an exsternal xml source, the array is called $file, I know that the php array is populated by using print_r($file).

I have tried to use the following php to pass to a javascript session:

```
//Convert to JSON Array
$jsonarray = json_encode($file, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$result["json_array"]=$jsonarray;
```

But either this hasn't worked, or the following JS code below is wrong:

```
var jsonarray = result["json_array"];

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonarray));
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you mixing PHP and JS variables?

Comment: In addition, you may want to use console.log() as opposed to alert. It'll give you more information about what is contained in the object being passed to it - especially if you are dealing with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use JSON.stringify there. JSON.parse is what you are looking for. Since you want to parse existing JSON, not create new JSON.

edit: Your code is a bit odd. I'd think you want something like this

php

```
//Convert to JSON Array
echo json_encode($file, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

js

```
alert(JSON.parse(data)); // Where data is the contents you've fetched from the server
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encapsulate php code :

```
<?php
$jsonarray = json_encode($file, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$result["json_array"]=$jsonarray;
?>

var jsonarray = <?= $result["json_array"] ?>;

alert(JSON.parse(jsonarray));
```